# Hide second row of table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row, hide

The first row is the container for search results to be displayed after user types in a keyword and hit search. The second row displays 5 random news results automatically the first time the website loads with no user queries. after the site loads, user types in some keyword and hit search. Now both the results returned as per user keyword and the 5 news pieces will be there. Based on whether the url has any querystring appended to it, if yes, I need to hide the second row. How do i select the second row?

Let's say if the url is just: http://mysite/news/pages/default.aspx then don't do anything
if the url is sth like  http://mysite/news/Pages/default.aspx?k=city, then hide the second row...

```
 <div class="NewsResultsList">   
        <table border="1" id="table">
            <tr><td>News Results based on user queries</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Random news results</td></tr>
         </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if you're suggesting that the script should sniff the URL. Don't do that. Instead, handle the emptying of the table in the `success` function of your callback, or do it server side if that's where things are rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to this selector

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('div.NewsResultsList table tr:eq(1)').remove()
})​
```

[here's the live example](http://jsfiddle.net/WWYp9/1/)

Note : you should change the id of the row to other name because with that id you could create confusion in your code

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `$(".NewsResultsList table tr :nth-child(2)").hide();`.

Answer (score 2):

```
//This will hide the second row of the table.
$(".NewsResultsList table tr").eq(1).hide();
```

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions. This is one I can think of:

```
$("#table").first().next().hide();
```